# How would I assign a dollar value to a name in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, weekly, I create a schedule for a league that looks like what I've posted below:

[image]

Each game and court has it's own referee.  Referees get paid either $5, $10 or $13 per game.  If there is a person's first name they receive $10, if it's a team name they receive $5 and if it's under the PL column, they receive $13.

I normally create the schedule in Word and have to manually calculate each referee credit (for doing this they receive credit off of their next season) and add it to an excel spreadsheet.  I'm hoping I can create the entire schedule in excel and attach a dollar value to each name so I don't have to manually calculate it.

It wouldn't be a big deal except I have to do this for 5 different schedules, each having 13 weeks and have to do it 6 times a year.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to somehow let Excel know what's a first name, team name, versus PL column. Have you looked at the [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-how-often-a-value-occurs-aa1f3067-05c9-44e4-b141-f75bb9bb89bd#bmcount_how_often_a_single_value_occurs) function?

Insert three columns at the end.

- First column AA are the names
- Second column AB will look at the range where the ref name occurs
  `=COUNTIF(F:N,AA2)`
  This function counts how many times the name in AA2 occurs
- Third column AC can multiple AB with the dollar value you assign 
  `=AB2*5`

[image]

You could further automate the payment calculation, but having another column and code it name, team, or PL and attribute it the right payment amount. Then Payment column takes that value to multiplies with the count.

Comment: But what if the team is playing, not reffing? That would be counted also, correct?

Comment: Yes, there could be false counts if the Ref name matched exactly. My assumption, which could be wrong, is that `Throwbocops V Michelle Montour` is one cell with carriage returns based on the layout. I can't see the row numbers in the image so only @Shannon would know for sure.

Comment: The image above was created in Word.  I would add team v team in one cell - so, your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have left a lot of details out about how you are planning to show the totals. So, I am making my answer a suggestion since you are faced with telling Excel the dollar value of each ref. My cell assignments are for example. You will have to make it work in your sheet.

I would create a separate table with the columns `ref name`, `$ Paid`, `Games`, `Total`. We will add a formula to the last two columns to find the total games reffed and then calculate the total to pay them.

In the column for `Games` use the following formula in `O2` to count the the number of games reffed by looking for the names in the `Ref`.

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,M2)+COUNTIF(G:G,M2)+COUNTIF(I:I,M2)
```

Then in the `Total` column (`P2`), simply multiply the `Games` by the `$ Paid`.

```
=O2*N2
```

Now select `O2:P2` and copy down to the bottom of the ref list.

In my example below, I have used columns `E`, `G` & `I` as the ref assignments from your example. This will only search the ref assignments and not the court assignments.

[image]

*NOTE: This is an example and not a correct calculation of the example you gave.*